# converting a differential equation to polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

I have the following family of autonomous systems, I'm having trouble with part b):

$$x'=x(1-\sqrt {x^2+y^2})-y-\epsilon y$$
$$y'=y(1-\sqrt {x^2+y^2})+x+\epsilon(x+x^2+y^2)$$

a) Convert the system to polar coordinates $(r(t;r_0,\theta_0,\epsilon),\theta(t;r_0,\theta_0,\epsilon))$:

$$x=r\cos\theta \qquad y=r\sin\theta \qquad r^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$x'=r'\cos\theta - r\sin\theta\theta' \quad y'=r'\sin\theta + r\cos\theta\theta'$$

$$\left ( \begin{array}\\ \cos{\theta} & -r \sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & r \cos{\theta} \end{array} \right ) \left ( \begin{array}\\ r' \\ \theta' \end{array} \right ) = \left ( \begin{array}\\ r\cos\theta(1-r)-r\sin\theta-\epsilon r \sin\theta\\r\sin\theta(1-r) + r\cos\epsilon + \epsilon(r\cos\theta+r^2) \end{array} \right )$$

I found the inverse matrix:

$$\left ( \begin{array}\\ \cos{\theta} & -r \sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & r \cos{\theta} \end{array} \right )^{-1}=\left ( \begin{array}\\ \cos{\theta} &  \sin{\theta} \\ \frac{-1}{r}\sin{\theta} & \frac{1}{r} \cos{\theta} \end{array} \right )$$

Multiplied on the left side, simplified and obtained:

$$\left ( \begin{array}\\ r' \\ \theta' \end{array} \right )=\left ( \begin{array}\\ r(1+\epsilon) \\1 + \epsilon r \end{array} \right )$$

b)See that for $\epsilon=0$ there is a periodic circular orbit with radius 1, period $2\pi$, and is **attractive**. In particular $(r(t;1,0,0),\theta(t;1,0,0))=(1,t)$.

For $\epsilon=0$ what I get is:

$$\left ( \begin{array}\\ r' \\ \theta' \end{array} \right )=\left ( \begin{array}\\ r \\ 1 \end{array} \right )$$

$$r'(t)=r(t) \quad \theta'(t)=1$$

Therefore $\theta (t)=t$ matches the initial value problem $\theta(t;1,0,0)=t$. However $r(t)=r'(t)$ can't match the initial value problem $r(t;1,0,0)=(1)$ because:

$$r(t)=1 \Rightarrow r'(t)=0 \Rightarrow r(t) \neq r'(t)$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Good work on the LaTeX formatting and excellent question. +1!

Comment: Check your left matrix multiplication

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to do the polar form change is to differentiate $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ and hence $r' = (xx' + yy')/r$. When you substitute for $x,y$ you should find
$$ r'= r(1-r) + \epsilon r^2\sin\theta.$$
When $\epsilon = 0$ the dynamics of $r$ decouples from $\theta$ and we can see we have a unstable fixed point(in $r$) at $r=0$ and a stable (and hence attracting) fixed point at $r=1$.

We can do the same thing by differentiating $\tan\theta = y/x$ and hence $r^2\theta' = y'x-x'y  $. Again, substituting gives
$$\theta' = 1  + \epsilon(1 + r\cos\theta).$$
When $\epsilon = 0$, $\theta' =1$ and $\theta = t+ \theta_0$.

Now you can use the face that $r=1$ implies $r'=0$, and use the initial conditions for $\theta_0$ to answer the question.

Comment: Awesome! :) I am glad to know that all my matrix math worked out. I got the same answers you did.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left ( \begin{array}\\ \cos{\theta} & -r \sin{\theta} \\ \sin{\theta} & r \cos{\theta} \end{array} \right )^{-1}= \left ( \begin{array}\\ \cos{\theta} &  \sin{\theta} \\ \frac{-1}{r}\sin{\theta} & \frac{1}{r} \cos{\theta} \end{array} \right )$$

Multiplied on the left side, simplified and obtained:
$$\left ( \begin{array}\\ \cos{\theta} &  \sin{\theta} \\ \frac{-1}{r}\sin{\theta} & \frac{1}{r} \cos{\theta} \end{array} \right ) * \left ( \begin{array}\\ r\cos\theta(1-r)-r\sin\theta-\epsilon r \sin\theta\\r\sin\theta(1-r) + r\cos\theta + \epsilon(r\cos\theta+r^2) \end{array} \right )$$
$$\left ( \begin{array}
*r\cos^2\theta (1-r)-r\sin\theta\cos\theta-\epsilon r \sin\theta\cos\theta+r\sin^2\theta(1-r) + r\cos\theta\sin\theta + \epsilon\sin\theta (r\cos\theta+r^2) 
\\ -\sin\theta \cos\theta(1-r)+\sin^2\theta+\epsilon \sin^2 \theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta(1-r)+\cos^2\theta+\epsilon(\cos^2 \theta+r\cos\theta)
\end{array} \right )$$

Cancel out:
$$\left ( \begin{array}  +r(1-r) + \epsilon\sin\theta r^2
\\ +1+\epsilon+\epsilon r\cos\theta
\end{array} \right )$$
Doesn't equal:
$$\left ( \begin{array}\\ r' \\ \theta' \end{array} \right )=\left ( \begin{array} \\ r(1+\epsilon) \\1 + \epsilon r \end{array} \right )$$

Comment: Working on formatting, please don't downvote what looks like an incomplete answer. :)

Comment: Np, I'm patient enough ^^

Comment: I've checked up through and inclusive of inverse matrix, and you look fine.

Comment: Damn, this is why I hate matrix multiplication. Big thanks for helping me through it =D

Comment: can some one please explain this step from above post........... ""differentiating $\tan\theta = y/x$ and hence $r^2\theta' = y'x-x'y  $"" ........how differentiateing $tan\theta$ bring such results.

Comment: @ttz  differentiate both sides $$\frac {\theta '}{\cos^2 \theta}=\frac {y'x-x'y}{x^2}$$ then $$ {\theta '}=\frac {y'x-x'y}{r^2}$$ since $x= r \cos \theta$