# Does local stability of a unique equilibrium in a bounded region implies global stability?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

If I have a non-linear system of ODE's, $\dot{\mathbf{x}} = f(\mathbf{x})$, where $f(\mathbf{\cdot})$ is a smooth non-linear function. Additionally, I know that $\mathbf{x}$ is bounded and the system has only a unique steady state that is locally asymptotically stable, $\mathbf{x}^*$. Is it wrong to conclude that $\mathbf{x}^*$ is globally asymptotically stable? I feel like it is too naive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of counterexamples, many of them taken from "real life" problems, but let me build one just from scratch.  In dimension two, take a system written in polar coordinates as
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{r} = -r (r - 1)^2
\\
\dot{\theta} = 1.
\end{cases}
$$
The system has one, locally asymptotically stable equilibrium $(0,0)$ (in Cartesian coordinates), with attraction basin equal to $\{(x,y) : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$, one periodic orbit $\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$, unstable from inside and asymptotically stable from outside.  All solutions are bounded in positive time.  Moreover, the disk $\{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$ is the global attractor.

Comment: Thanks. I failed to mention the non-existence of periodic solution, but that is pretty hard to show in dim>3 anyway.

Comment: For such a system in dimension 2, **without periodic solutions**, see pp. 21-22 of [Stability Theory of Dynamical Systems](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783540427483) by Bhatia and Szegő (with time reversed).

Comment: @ user539887  In your maintained system  is not two equilibrium points $r=0$ and $r=1$.  If it is, then the answer is not according to the problem.

Comment: @SAHEBPAL There is only one equilibrium, namely $(0,0)$.

Comment: @ user539887 How? Can you explain ? I am confused with polar coordinates. I know that for a continuous Cartesian system $\dot x=f(x)$  equilibrium solution are given by $f(x)=0$

Comment: You can see, for instance, [Polar coordinates differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541889/polar-coordinates-differential-equation), or [Solve the dynamical system in polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766983/solve-the-dynamical-system-in-polar-coordinates), or else [converting a differential equation to polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325594/converting-a-differential-equation-to-polar-coordinates).